# Flutter display image picked from gallery

Tags: flutter, dart, image-gallery, flutter-futurebuilder, imagepicker

I am simply trying to pick an image and display it inside my app. For that I am using [Flutter Image Picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker). I added all the dependencies and I can select an image but I can not display it...

This is what I tried:

```
class _AddMemoryPageState extends State<AddMemoryPage> {
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  late Future<PickedFile?> pickedFile;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppColors.secondary,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 15,
                    left: 25,
                  ),
                  child: IconButtonWithExpandedTouchTarget(
                    onTapped: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    svgPath: 'assets/icons/down.svg',
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                IconButtonWithExpandedTouchTarget(
                  onTapped: () async {
                    pickedFile = picker
                        .getImage(
                          source: ImageSource.camera,
                        )
                        .whenComplete(() => {setState(() {})});
                  },
                  svgPath: 'assets/icons/camera.svg',
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: scaleWidth(50),
                ),
                IconButtonWithExpandedTouchTarget(
                  onTapped: () async {
                    pickedFile = picker
                        .getImage(
                          source: ImageSource.gallery,
                        )
                        .whenComplete(() => {setState(() {})});
                  },
                  svgPath: 'assets/icons/gallery.svg',
                ),
              ],
            ),
            FutureBuilder(
              future: pickedFile,
              builder: (context, data) {
                if (data.hasData) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 200.0,
                    child: Image.file(
                      data.data as File,
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                      height: 200.0,
                    ),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  );
                }
                return Container(
                  height: 200.0,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

However this is not working:

> LateInitializationError: Field 'pickedFile' has not been initialized.

What am I missing here? What is the proper way to handle this? I couldn't find any up-to-date tutorial/docs on this.. Let me know if you need any more info!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically forgot to transform de PickerFile in a File and init the variable pickedFile `late Future<PickedFile?> pickedFile = Future.value(null);`.

To transform the PickerFile in a file, you just need to do:

```
File(data.data!.path)
```

I made some modifies at your code, that can show the image now:

```dart
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  late Future<PickedFile?> pickedFile = Future.value(null);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 15,
                    left: 25,
                  ),
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.download_rounded),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    pickedFile = picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera).whenComplete(() => {setState(() {})});
                  },
                  icon:Icon(Icons.add)
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 100,
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    pickedFile = picker
                        .getImage(
                      source: ImageSource.gallery,
                    )
                        .whenComplete(() => {setState(() {})});
                  },
                  icon:Icon(Icons.photo_camera_back),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            FutureBuilder<PickedFile?>(
              future: pickedFile,
              builder: (context, snap) {
                if (snap.hasData) {
                  return Container(
                    child: Image.file(
                      File(snap.data!.path),
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    ),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  );
                }
                return Container(
                  height: 200.0,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: is this working for you correctly? If I pick an image, I dont see it on my screen. The blue Container stays there

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to initialize 'pickedFile' in setState? And also
PickedFile type is not File type so convert it like this "Image.file(data.data.path)" as stated in image_picker documentation `final pickedFile = await _picker.getImage(...); final File file = File(pickedFile.path);`.

Comment: how should I init in setState? Can not make it work with the FutureBuilder